# Efeito Parallax não está funcionando em mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um novo website aqui da empresa http://teste.softlove.us/

E tudo está funcionando (efeitos e tamanhos), estou utilizando Bootstrap e jQuery, exceto no mobile que na Home e About Us possui o efeito Parallax.

O mesmo não funciona em qualquer dispositivo mobile... alguém pode me ajudar ?

```css
  /* formata elementos que tem backgrounds parallax */
.bgParallax {
  color:#FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1000px; 
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
 
/* Define backgrounds dos divs */
#quemsomos {
  background-image: url(http://teste.softlove.us/assets/img/home/bg_usa2.png);
 }
```

```html
<div id="quemsomos" class="bgParallax" data-speed="15">
  <p>EXEMPLO</p>
  </div>
```

O problema é que testando pelos navegadores na resolução do dispositivo mobile x ele aparenta funcionar. Mas ao testar no dispositivo nada acontece :(

O que pode ocasionar isso?

Comment: verifiquei que o efeito parallax está funcionando em seu site. Acessei por um iphone 5. Como você fez?

Comment: utilizei sem js, fiz na unha o efeito em css

Comment: Qual a solução que usou? Poderia mostrar?? Pfv haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os dispositivos mobile não detectam a rolagem da mesma forma que os navegadores.

Provavelmente quando você testa no celular, o efeito só acontece quando a animação da rolagem do navegador chega ao fim.

Uma dica é usar o modernizr para detectar se o navegador suporta eventos de touch. Se não suporta (navegadores desktop) você aplica o javascript do parallax, e se suporta (navegadores mobile) você não aplica e pode deixar a imagem sendo exibida de outra forma.

Comment: olá @dian , infelizmente não sei utilizar o modernizr ainda... mas entendi sua colocação...

Comment: @RafaelRotiroti, para usar o modernizr nesse caso, é só ir no site https://modernizr.com/download e escolher na lista a opção "TouchEvents". Clica no botão rosa "Build" la em cima e escolhe a opção "Download" na primeira linha (Build). Assim vai ser baixado um .js, inclua ele em seu projeto e no javascript você vai conseguir verificar:

`if (Modernizr.touchevents) {
  // suporta touch - dispositivo moveis
} else {
  // não suporta - navegadores desktop
}`

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é deixar a imagem com "position: fixed" e deixar o z-index menor do que os demais elementos, funciona com vídeos também.